# Why isn't sgn'(0) = 0? Related to the theorem lim f'(c) = C => f'(c) = C

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know the name of this theorem but I learned it in class and it says: If function f is defined at (a, b) and there exists c such that a < c < b, and function f has derivatives on (a, c) U (c, b), then if
lim f '(x) = C when x -> c then f '(c) exists and f '(c) = C. Now I know that sgn(x) doesn't have a derivative at x = 0, but sgn'(x) = 0 when x is not equal to 0. And it is defined at these points so it has left and right limits when x -> 0+/- and they equal 0. So it has limit when x -> 0, i.e. lim sgn'(x) = 0 when x -> 0 so why isn't sgn'(0) = 0 rather then being undefined?

Answer (score 4):

That theorem requires you to assume $f$ is continuous at $c$. But $\text{sgn}$ is not continuous at $0$ (so of course it cannot be differentiable at $0$). In fact this example shows you why you need to assume continuity at the point.

Comment: Okay thank you, it must be a mistake in my notes.